# QuickBook Online API Exclude discount on Shipping Service Line Item

Tags: php, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

```
        $lineItemsArray['Id'] = rand();
        $lineItemsArray['LineNum'] = rand();
        $lineItemsArray['Description'] = 'Insta Soup';
        $lineItemsArray['Amount'] = 333;
        $lineItemsArray['DetailType'] = 'SalesItemLineDetail';
        $lineItemsArray['SalesItemLineDetail'] = array(
                                                "ItemRef" =>array('name'=>'insta soup','value'=>'10'),
                                                "UnitPrice"=> 333,
                                                "Qty"=> 1
```

I am adding shipping as a line item in creating an invoice request which is a service type line item. Now when I am adding a percentage discount line item for a discount, it is applying on shipping service as well when checking in QBO invoices. I don't want to apply the discount on shipping fee item but only on other line items or their total. Is there any way to exclude service from discount.